# Can i have two kafka consumer in single mule app? both subscribed to different topics

Tags: apache-kafka, mule

I want to listen for message from two different topic. Can i configure two consumer in single mule app ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it passes properties directly to the Kafka API, Mule should support topic regex patterns if not a list, so yes